# Hide horizontal CSS menu overflow

Tags: css, positioning

I have a horizontal drop down CSS menu at http://www.stevemoorecpa.dreamhosters.com/

My problem is the menu width extends outside the site's wrapper and I cannot get it to hide.

[image: Example of problem]

How do you prevent the element from going outside the site wrapper? Here is the code for the wrapper...

```
#wrapperSkm {
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: transparent;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #c3c3c3;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #c3c3c3;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #c3c3c3;
    width:1069px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0px 0 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background:url(images/line1Right.png) repeat-x right 134px;
}
```

And here is the code for the horizontal sub-menu navigation

```
#access ul ul {
    display: none;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 181px;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    background:#fff url(images/line1Nav.png) repeat-x bottom;
    z-index: 99999;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I've been working at this all day and nothing will get the menu to hide it's overflow outside the main site wrapper.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HI now add `position relative` in your `wrapperSkm` **ID**

as like this

```
#wrapperSkm{
position: relative;
}
```

**result is**

[image]

Comment: Is there an article or something that explains why this works? That is, how `overflow: hidden` and `position: relative` work together?

Comment: Wow I should have asked this days ago. I couldn't find my error. Thank you so much.

Comment: @TomSmilack now more info chech to this http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/110-quick-overview-of-css-position-values/  and this http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/

Comment: @TomSmilack *An absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static applied to it.* http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-positioning/ , that's why `position: relative` is likely (or ALWAYS ;) ) to be set on a parent of an absolutely positioned element. `overflow: hidden` is another beast (and I tend to avoid it most of the time as it'll bite me later in most projects). It creates a [Block Formatting Context](http://www.tjkdesign.com/articles/block-formatting-contexts_and_hasLayout.asp) (reliable source: T. Koblentz)